# Insert command denied for another IP

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, proxy

I'm using Selenium WebClient & WebDriver behind a **proxy** server.

And database transactions is done via **Hibernate** on my MySQL DB server.
I'm confused with the following error:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: INSERT command denied to user 'user'@'**another_IP**' for table 'myTable'
```

I'm confused completely with this fact that '**another_IP**' is my proxy IP but I'm using the proxy just for Selenium not Hibernate connections!!!! 
In the other words, my VPS server (*sending not only sending web requests but also do db transactions on a remote MySQL DB server, **DB_Server_IP**, by Hibernate*), has **My_IP** and I'm sending the web requests to web pages, not db transactions, via proxy with IP **another_IP**. Now, my DB server should receives db transaction requests only from **My_IP**, BUT It receives from **another_IP**!!!

Comment: How do you activate your proxy?

Comment: @OrtomalaLokni What do you means by activating my proxy?! I'm using a free proxy server such as: 10.2.3.4:8118 in my selenium webdriver initialization.

Answer (score -1):

Hibernate has nothing to do in that case .

I think you have not given enough privileges to that MySQL user account on that ip.

Execute this SQL : `GRANT SELECT, INSERT, DELETE ON db.* TO 'user'@'anotherip';`

and then try to execute the INSERT query.

Update :

If problem is still there, create a MySQL account with that ip :

Execute this SQL : `CREATE USER 'user'@'anotherip' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';`

and then execute the above command with the insert query.

Comment: Be sure, be sure, be sure!!! that I know how to grant privileges to a user@ip in MySQL. Understanding why my Hibernate requests are passing via my proxy. Note that I'm using the proxy only when I send web requests for web pages not for hibernate requests. Why my db server receive requests from my proxy IP?? It should receive only from my vps IP not my proxy IP....!!!!!

Comment: Did you know that punctuation marks in singular form is effective? And multiple just makes you look rambling and incoherent? I guess it was an effective warning. Did you think to ask your VPS provider how things are set up? Because obviously we can't change it for you. What answer did you really expect apart from a quick one to get you working?

Comment: @danblack I'm looking for an answer that explains why MySQL installed on VPS receives requests from another_IP not from My_IP!

Comment: Ask your VPS provider. There are a number of ways and reasons to proxy mysql. Last point on punctuation marks, a single full stop is ok. You won't get a better answer with an exclamation mark, most likely the opposite will ocur. And ask your VPS provider and how they proxy mysql and how you should be using it.